# How to make a loop inside an if statement

Tags: loops, if-statement

So I was asked to do this

(JavaScript)

"Make a text box and if a certain number is entered and submitted, it loop. Example, enter 1 and it will loop from 1 to 10, enter 3 and it will loop from 3 to 30 and etc."

So I'm asking how to actually do it since I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: I can't figure out what "etc" means. What if you enter 2 ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'll need more information to properly help you: what have you tried so far and what specifically is going wrong? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is it you are actually asking?

Comment: By I mean etc, any number that is entered will be multiplied by 10 and will be looped. For Example, I enter 9, and it will be looped from 9 to 90 because 9 x 10 is 90. Edit: Sorry made a mistake in the question itself, I mean 1 to 10, not 1 to 20.

Answer (score 1):

you can do like below:
where `inputVal` is the value in the textBox.

```
for(var i=inputVal;i<=inputVal*10;i++)
{
   console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: Although I applaud the attempt to answer the question, OP hasn't even stated what language they are using...